# Trying to understand difficult Perl syntax: array and empty square braces

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to analyze a piece of Perl code that contains the following:

```
unless( @{$avl->Rates() || []} ) {
  if(!$nobar) { push @rptmp, 'BAR' unless @rptmp; }
}
```

The inner action I think I understand. It means "if $nobar is false (0 in this case) then add the string 'BAR' to the array `@rptmp` unless `@rptmp` already exists."

The part I am having trouble with is the first "unless" condition: `unless ( @{$avl->Rates() || []} )`. `$avl->Rates()` is a function that returns a list (or maybe a pointer to a list?). But the really confusing part for me is the `|| []`. This is "or" something, so it is not selected unless `$avl->Rates()` returns nothing. But I am not sure what it does, especially the empty square brackets. And if it is returning something that is empty, wouldn't it always be false? Also, is there a better, or at least clearer, way to write this?

Comment: That is horrible Perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. Lets look at this. I think it's dreadful Perl but others clearly disagree. There are many people who have issues with `unless` (meaning simply `if not`) and in situations like this I sympathise: there's simply too much going on

Here's the whole thing

```
unless ( @{ $avl->Rates() || [] } ) {
  if ( !$nobar ) { push @rptmp, 'BAR' unless @rptmp; }
}
```

First of all I would extract the call to `Rates` like this

```
my $rates = $avl->Rates();
unless ( @{ $rates || [] } ) {
  if ( !$nobar ) { push @rptmp, 'BAR' unless @rptmp; }
}
```

I don't know what `$avl` might be, but it looks like its `Rates` method will return either an array reference or a *false* value -- probably `undef`. So the expression `$rates || []` defaults anything *false* to a reference to an enpty array. Now the enclosing `@{ ... }` can dereference it safely either way

The test is whether the array is empty, and I would write

```
unless ( $rates and @$rates )
```

i.e. *unless the `Rates` method returned a* true *value and it was a reference to a non-empty array*

Now we have the inner statement with another `unless`, except that this time it is  written as `if not`, and inside it there is a real `unless`

```
if ( !$nobar ) {
    push @rptmp, 'BAR' unless @rptmp;
}
```

The inner statement is simple. It tests `@rptmp`, which is *true* unless the array is empty, and pushes `BAR` onto it *only* if it is empty

The enclosing conditional checks what is presumably an option `$nobar`, and if it is *true* then `BAR` is never pushed onto the array, regardless of any other conditions

I would refactor the whole thing this way, extracting the method call separately and using `unless` throughout

```
my $rates = $avl->Rates;

unless ( $rates and @$rates) {
    unless ( $nobar ) {
        push @rptmp, 'BAR' unless @rptmp;
    }
}
```

If you are `unless`-phobic, then here's a version that uses only `if` throughout, but I find it less readable

```
my $rates = $avl->Rates;

if ( not $rates or @$rates == 0 ) {
    if ( not $nobar ) {
        push @rptmp, 'BAR' if @rptmp == 0;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I am still having a mental block regarding the || [ ]. I understand (please correct me if I am wrong) that if the $avl->Rates() expression returns undef, then [ ] creates an empty anonymous array and returns a reference to it. But what is the purpose of that? Is the empty array useful for anything itself, or is it only there to prevent the conditional expression from producing an error if the first expression is undef?

Comment: Pretty much. It's so that the `@{ ... }` doesn't have to dereference `undef` which doesn't make sense and would cause a fatal error if `use strict` is in effect as it should be

Answer (score 5):

> *so it is not selected unless `$avl->Rates()` returns nothing*

It's impossible for it to return nothing in scalar context. Presumably, it returns either a reference to an array or undef. `unless (@{ $avl->Rates })` would fail in the latter case, so the coder decided to use a reference to an empty array in that case.

```
[]
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
# Create an array, and return a reference to it.
do { my @anon; \@anon }
```

It's a little wasteful, but

```
if (!@{ $avl->Rates() || [] }) {
   ...
}
```

is commonly used since it's shorter than

```
my $rates = $avl->Rates();
if (!$rates || !@$rates) {
   ...
}
```

---

The following is clearer, and avoids calling `Rates` when it's not needed:

```
if (!$nobar && !@rptmp) {
   my $rates = $avl->Rates;
   push @rptmp, 'BAR'
      if !$rates || !@$rates;
}
```

Comment: *"It's impossible for it to return nothing in scalar context"* That's getting a bit meta. It's impossible for any subroutine to return without defining a return stack. If by *nothing* you mean `undef`, an empty list, or any *false* value then yea, it's possible, but the context is irrelevant unless you define your *nothing* so that it is

Comment: @Borodin, In general, subs return zero or more scalars. In scalar context, they must always return a scalar.

Comment: Or, in list context, a list

Comment: I mean that it seems you've decided that your *nothing* is an empty list, ergo it can't be returned in scalar context. The OP is free to define his *nothing* as `undef`. I'm just saying your first sentence doesn't mean much

Comment: @Borodin, Returning a variable is not returning nothing. You must return a scalar in scalar context. It's impossible to do otherwise (except from broken XS code, which results in crashes). He can define `undef` to mean "no rates", but that's irrelevant; he still returned an undefined scalar.

Comment: You're missing my point. Perl doesn't define *nothing*, so you can't say that a subroutine can't return it. And `undef` isn't a variable!

Comment: @Borodin, Yes, I can. If you have to return one of something, you can't return nothing. As you said, it returns "either an array reference or a false value".

Answer (score 0):

The `unless @rptmp` bit means do this unless `@rptmp` is not empty.

Empty square brackets are are a reference to an empty array.

`@{...}` is dereferencing whatever is in the curly braces and evaluating it as an array.

So, `$avl->Rates()` presumably returns either a reference to an array or 0. If it returns 0, The first `unless` above will evaluate `[]` instead. Dereferencing `$avl->Rates() || []` will either get you the array pointed to by the array reference returned by `$avl->Rates()`, or an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

To answer

> Also, is there a better, or at least clearer, way to write this?

No. This *is* the clear way. It's very idiomatic in Perl; you'll find it a lot.